# Can't remove lock file in sysemd unit files

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd, rhel7

I'm having a really weird problem with systemd on RHEL7.The /run/puppetboot.lock file is not being removed at the end of execution for the unit file. Strangely, when I replace the 'puppet agent' lines with '/usr/bin/true', then them lock file is deleted as expected.

```
[Unit]
Description=Extra Puppet runs
Wants=basic.target
Before=puppet.service
After=basic.target network.target puppetmaster.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/puppetagent
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/puppet
ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch /run/puppetboot.lock
ExecStart=/usr/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --ignoreschedules
ExecStart=/usr/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --ignoreschedules
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/puppetboot.lock
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/test -x /usr/local/sbin/reboot-if-needed && /usr/local/sbin/reboot-if-needed"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target puppet.service
```

I'm using the lock file as a signal that the early-booting config and setup is done so that I can send an email to the admins for post-build configuration. I'm hoping to avoid adding a systemd unit file just to send me nag emails after a new server is built.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, But I think is useless to specify twice "ExecStart=/usr/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --ignoreschedules"

Comment: I deliberately run puppet twice. It's NOT useless. I currently run puppet three times shortly after boot to have the machine be quickly configured without waiting an hour or so. The third puppet run is the normal puppet service. My machines don't converge until the second or third puppet run.

Comment: Could it be that puppet returns a zon-zero exit code and the remaining ExecStarts are not run? Try prefixing the puppet lines with a dash: i.e. ExecStart=-/usr/bin/puppet ... See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart= and see if the lock file is then deleted

Comment: if you don't want to wait one hour for puppet execution, you can you use runinteval option for change the puppet exection time.

Comment: Per @Jukka, I added the '-' to the beginning of the puppet lines, and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @c4f4t0r the default 30 minute run interval is fine for normal use, but I need the multiple runs at boot for the initial build and for larger updates. I also manage desktop machines with this config, and I want to postpone the login screen until the machine config is mostly sane. I don't want end users attempt to login when the system isn't fully configured. End users tend to complain when they login and the machine isn't fully configured.

Comment: yes, I know your point of view, but you don't need "ExecStart=/usr/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --ignoreschedules" twice, because your configuration change can be apply with the first run.

Comment: My puppet configuration is fairly complex and needs multiple runs to apply everything.  I have multiple implicit dependencies between modules. As I understand, it's not best practice for puppet modules to have 'requires' and other explicit dependencies between modules. I work around the implicit dependencies by having modules skip the run if the implicit dependency is not met. I haven't bothered with puppet stages.